# guice ignores providers?

Tags: annotations, guice, provider

It seems Guice is ignoring my @Provider methods of my module.

I have a class MyModule like this:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {

        bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Timed.class), new GuiceEnabledLoggingInterceptor());
        bind(OneClass.class).to(OneClassImpl.class);

        // And more binding lines...

    }

    @Provides
    public AnotherClassInApi provideMyClass() {
        return AnotherClassInApi.getInstance();
    }

    // And more @Provides methods

}
```

Main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ConfigHandler.getInstance().loadConfigWhenNotRunningInsideMicrocontainer();
    Injector INJECTOR = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    // ...
}
```

In some other part of the project I have class AnotherClassInApi, which is a very standard singleton plus one method:

```
public class AnotherClassInApi {

    private static final AnotherClassInApi INSTANCE = new AnotherClassInApi();

    private AnotherClassInApi() { }

    // ... more methods

    public static AnotherClassInApi getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Well, I understand that should effectively bind any request for an AnotherClassInApi object to the getInstance() method, but it doesn't work. Funny thing, a breakpoint in the @Provide method is never reached while debugging, but one in the configure method is reached. It seems guice is ignoring my provider annotation, and I think [I'm following exactly what Guice guide says about @Provider](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods), so I'm already stuck.

I've been googling around, but can't find anything similar. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your actual `@Inject` point look like where you ask for an instance of `AnotherClassInApi`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of Providers (and @Provides methods) is, that they are only called when actually needed. So unless you really use your Injector to create an instance that has an @Inject dependency, your Provider is not ignored, just not used (nor needed).

You can monitor all configured bindings by using "[injector.getAllBindings()](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Injector.html)".

> java.util.Map,Binding> getAllBindings()
>
> Returns a snapshot
>   of this injector's bindings, both explicit and just-in-time. The
>   returned map is immutable; it contains only the bindings that were
>   present when getAllBindings() was invoked. Just-in-time bindings are
>   only present if they have been requested at least once. Subsequent
>   calls may return a map with additional just-in-time bindings. The
>   returned map does not include bindings inherited from a parent
>   injector, should one exist.
>
> This method is part of the Guice SPI and is intended for use by tools
>   and extensions.

Comment: This link is broken now.